# Mysterious "extra argument" error when running an instance method from initializer

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I'm trying to make Conway's Game of Life in python. Basically, I need to make a grid/2d list and fill it out with values. I have the grid registered as a Grid object. The object pointer is an attribute of the Game object.

For some reason when I try to run an instance method on the Grid, python says it "setCell expected 3 positional arguments and got 4". But I only gave 3. See code below:

I thought maybe it was an issue with the "self" variable, but using a "tempgrid" wrapper-proxy thing to hold the grid didn't seem to work. (The dashed lines represent separate files)

```py
class Cell:
    def __init__(self, xpos, ypos, status):
        self.xpos = xpos
        self.ypos = ypos
        self.status = status
----------------
from .cell import Cell

class Grid:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.size = size
        self.cells = [[None for _ in range(size)] for _ in range(size)]

    def setCell(xpos, ypos, status):
        cells[xpos][ypos] = Cell(xpos, ypos, status)
------------------------
from .grid import Grid

class Game:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.grid = Grid(size)

        for i in range(size):
            for j in range(size):
                self.grid.setCell(i, j, 0) #python says this is supposed to have 3 arguments but has 4, even though I give 3
```

What's going on? For reference, the exact error message is "TypeError: setCell() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given"

Comment: you forgot `self` in `def setCell(self, xpos, ypos, status):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot `self` in

```
def setCell(self, xpos, ypos, status):
```

When you run

```
self.grid.setCell(i, j, 0)
```

then Python runs

```
Grid.setCell(self.grid, i, j, 0)
```

so it needs 4 arguments in definition

(and then it can assign `self.grid` to `self`)

Comment: thank you so much! not only did you fix my problem, but I finally understand how "self" works in python... coming from Java it's been confusing. im so happy :))

Comment: you can also run `Grid.setCell(self.grid, i, j, 0)` and it will work.